# Php replace line in a file txt

Tags: php, replace, line

```
<?php
$myFile = "/home/user1/www/cgi-bin/mytext.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);
$lines[3] = $_POST['title'];
file_put_contents($myFile , implode("\n", $lines));
?>
```

I would change only the row "number 3" without changing the other rows, where mistake?

i have input mytext.txt:

- line1 -------------------------------------
- line2 #WORD:
- line3 CHANGETHIS
- line4
- line5 HELLO
- line6 PIPPO
- line7 FOO
- line8 KATEEOWEN

after lunch script this is the ouput mytext.txt:

- line1 -------------------------------------
- line2
- line3 #WORD:
- line4
- line5 CHANGETHIS
- line6
- line7 $_POST['title']
- line8 HELLO
- line9
- line10 PIPPO
- line11
- line12 FOO
- line13
- line14 KATEEOWEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` constant in `file()` or don't use more newlines:

```
file_put_contents($myFile , implode('', $lines));
```

Or just this as it will be imploded for you:

```
file_put_contents($myFile , $lines);
```

But you'll need to add a newline here:

```
$lines[3] = $_POST['title'] . "\n";
```

So this might be the most straight forward:

```
$lines = file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$lines[3] = $_POST['title'];
file_put_contents($myFile , implode("\n", $lines));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use str_replace function without problem

look this

```
 str_replace('line3 CHANGETHIS', 'line3 #WORD:', $file_content)
```

and then save result of function to file

Comment: I need to replace line 3 with the value $_POST['title'] from my form html